# How to create subfloat figures (two in first row and one below)?

Tags: positioning, subfloats

I want to place three figures like this on the page:

```
(a) (b)
  (c)
```

How do I achieve this using subfloat or any other method in LaTeX?
The three figures need to have a common caption and label.

I have tried this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\subfloat[] { \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{1.pdf} }
&
\subfloat[] { \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{2.pdf} }
\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}
\subfloat[] { \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{3.pdf} }
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{some-label}
\end{figure}
```

But, this is displaying `[]` for the third figure instead of `(c)`.
Also it displays `[]` to one side of the page instead of center.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I understand what you would like, then one method would be to use a couple of minipages and the `subfig` package.  Spacing etc. could be adjusted to your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:a}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:b}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:c}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-c}}

\caption{my fig}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 37):

Here's a possible solution using the `subfigure` environment from the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{image1}
\caption{}
\label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{image2}
\caption{}
\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}\\[1ex]
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{image3}
\caption{}
\label{fig:sub3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Three subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

As we can see in Figures~\ref{fig:sub1}, \ref{fig:sub2}, and~\ref{fig:sub3}...

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` was only used to replace actual figures with black rectangles. Do *not* use that option in your actual document,

Comment: Hi, thanks. I upvoted. Is there a way for me to place the labels a, b and c on left of the figures instead of the bottom?

Comment: Nice thanks. In my document it only worked, when i DON'T use \centering in the 1st and 2nd subfigure. Just in the last subfigure.

Answer (score 8):

Using a linebreak (similar to Gonzalo's answer) the `subfig` package does the trick even without minipages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{figure}[ht]%
 \centering
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{UEB01-repograph1.pdf}\label{fig:a}}%
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{UEB01-repograph2.pdf}\label{fig:b}}\\
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{UEB01-repograph3.pdf}\label{fig:c}}%
 \caption{Some caption}%
 \label{some-label}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]
There might be drawbacks I don't know about in more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

I generally use `$\begin{array} FIGURES \end{array}$` to insert many graphs in one figure... No need for extra packages:

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
$\begin{array}{rl}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{FIGURE_1.pdf} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{FIGURE_2.pdf}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{FIGURE_3.pdf}}
\end{array}$
\caption[My beautiful figure.]{\label{fig:label}My beautiful figure}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Why not using the array equivalent for text? It would be `tabular`.

Comment: What about `subcaptions`?

Comment: For subcations I would use `minipage` I think