# Subfigures in triangle with the subfigure package

Tags: floats

I am trying to get three images as subfigures in this shape:

[image]

I want to do it with the package subfigures bacause the rest of my document is with that package and it seems to be incompatible with the package subcaption. I've seen several related questions (as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64858/how-to-create-subfloat-figures-two-in-first-row-and-one-below) one), but what I need to use is the subfigure package (not subfig and not subcaption).

Everything I've tried so far is not even compiling.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a minimal working example showing the problem? It should begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: The `subfigure` package is deprecated. It would be better to entirely switch to either `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: @GoldenFlecha did the answer below meet your requirements -- is there something else required -- please let us know

Comment: @GoldenFlecha did the answer below meet your requirements -- is there something else required -- please let us know

Answer (score 1):

### With `subfigure`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


    \begin{figure}[ht]

        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth} % this sets the figure to be max half the width of the page
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}  % this sets the image to fill 90% of the available space -> 45% of the line width in total. 
            \caption{Put your sub-captionB here}
            \label{fig:sub-first}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include second image
            \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-c}  
            \caption{Put your sub-captionC here}
            \label{fig:sub-second}
        \end{subfigure}

        \label{fig:fig}
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}   % this width should be half of the width of the other two images
            \caption{Put your sub-captionA here}
            \label{fig:sub-firstA}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Put your caption here}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### With `subfig/subfloat`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]%
 \centering
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{UEB01-repograph1.pdf}\label{fig:a}} \quad
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{UEB01-repograph2.pdf}\label{fig:b}}\\
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{UEB01-repograph3.pdf}\label{fig:c}}%
 \caption{Some caption}%
 \label{some-label}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### EDIT1

### Adding placement with `array`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]%
 \centering
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{UEB01-repograph1.pdf}\label{fig:a}} \quad
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{UEB01-repograph2.pdf}\label{fig:b}}\\
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{UEB01-repograph3.pdf}\label{fig:c}}%
 \caption{Some caption}%
 \label{some-label}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure*}[t!]
$\begin{array}{cc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{FIGURE_1.pdf} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{FIGURE_2.pdf}\\
    \textbf{fjhfj}& \textbf{fjhfj}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{FIGURE_3.pdf}}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{fjhfj}}
\end{array}$
\caption[My beautiful figure.]{\label{fig:label}My beautiful figure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

### With `minipage`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.58\textwidth} % almost 60%
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\caption{Mystery shack}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\caption{Nice landscape}
\end{subfigure}


\end{minipage} \par 
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.38\textwidth} % almost 40%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}

\caption{Rainbow gnome}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{Gravity falls}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first example is what I was look for. One thing: when you use [width=.9\linewidth] yuo are changing the size of the image to be 90% the original size, right? And other thing, the two figures that are side by side are different in size, is there a way to allign them so the captions are alligned to the one of the biggest figure?

Comment: @GoldenFlecha  `\captionsetup{skip=3pt} \caption{A subfigure}` -- --  the caption setup options are many and are given at page 6 -- http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf  -- and at page 13 -- -- http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf

Comment: The firs example is problematic. It use obsolete package `subfigure`. Instead it you should use `subfig` package (second example) or even beter `subcaption` package!